# Sharing on twitter using STTwitter?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, ios6, sttwitter

I am facing a problem in sharing of Twitter using the `STTwitter API`. I need to do multiple sharing on a single button click. For example, on the click of a sharing button I need to share the data on Facebook, Twitter and also on Tumblr at the same time.

A problem occurs while sharing on Twitter using the old API. It will open a Tweet sheet which I don't need to open. I want to simply share data on all three without any pop ups. So that's why I'm using `STTwitter` for sharing on twitter, but it doesn't work properly.

***ON CLICK OF SHARE BUTTON I HAVE WRITE THE FOLLOWING CODE*:**

```
[[TWAccessTokenGenerator sharedAccessTokenGenerator] initialize];

[self getTwitterTokens];
```

**SOME METHODS :**

```
void)getTwitterTokens
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(GettingAccessToken:) name:@"RefreshTwitterAccounts" object:nil];
[[TWAccessTokenGenerator sharedAccessTokenGenerator] refreshTwitterAccounts];
}
```

And like the above method there are some methods too but it doesn't share the data.

Comment: You might want to show what it is you're doing. Show us some code. I've removed the requests for tutorials. Such requests are not allowed on SO and will generally get your questions closed. If you have a problem with your code, show us your code. That we might be able to help you with.

Comment: @Bart: Actually i want to share data on twitter without opening tweet sheet,for that i have applied a method in which i'm again and again getting .....THIS ERROR MESSAGE:  -- regexError: Can't find a match for regex: <error>(.*)</error>
-- body: {"errors":[{"message":"Your credentials do not allow access to this resource","code":220}]}
 The operation couldn’t be completed. (STHTTPRequest error 403.)

Comment: STTwitter cannot post your status because of an authentication issue.

Try to isolate the problem and post some code to show the way you use STTwitter.

This way I'll be able to help you.